# Allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, tempdb, dbcc-checkdb

DBCC CHECKDB returns:

> Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage:
>   140737951236096' in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup
>   is full.
>
> Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping
>   objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or
>   setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.
>
> Msg 9002,
>   Level 17, State 4, Line 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is pretty self explanatory - your tempdb is full, and can't be grown to perform the operation it needs tempdb for.

As indicated, either the disk where it is located is full, or you haven't got suitable autogrowth settings ([see this earlier post for information about that](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20914/tempdb-autogrowth-settings)), if it's not autogrowth, you'll have to either delete other files from the disk that your tempdb is on, or locate your tempdb on a bigger disk.

[This sqlservercentral post](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1218997-146-1.aspx) is similar to yours and might take be worth a look. [This video by Brent Ozar](https://www.brentozar.com/sql/tempdb-performance-and-configuration/) might be worth a look too, covering tempdb performance and config.

Comment: My disk space is 10TB free out of 16TB .in same folder i do have other .mdf and .ldf files . Autogrowth for data file is 1000MB ,unlimited and log file 100MB limited to 2097152Mb .do you think i have to change autogrowth and maxsize ?@Ian_H

Answer (score 6):

Run this command to get the estimated *tempdb space* required for the check:

```
DBCC CHECKDB ('databasename') WITH ESTIMATEONLY
```

See the [`DBCC CHECKDB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql) documentation

> ESTIMATEONLY
>   Displays the estimated amount of tempdb space that is required to run DBCC CHECKDB with all the other specified options. The actual database check is not performed.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the below query and it released the unused space:

```
USE [tempdb]
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'tempdev' , 0, TRUNCATEONLY)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error message. It turns out that the physical disk was full. Our SQL Server admin deleted some history backups and changed backup mode from full to simple at some databases which had large transaction log and their purpose was for reporting and not for transaction's (application).