# dbo.SORT temporary run storage: 148643705716736' What does this number means?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, tempdb

I totally understand what this error means and how to resolve.

My question is what does this number (**148643705716736**) referring to?

> Date      5/7/2018 1:36:58 AM
>
> Log        SQL Server (Current - 5/7/2018 2:31:00
> AM)
>
> Source        spid125
>
> Message
>
> Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run
> storage:  **148643705716736**' in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY'
> filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files,
> dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the
> filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the
> filegroup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161462/allocate-space-for-object-dbo-sort-temporary-run-storage)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is most likely the `allocation_unit_id` that was attempting to be allocated when it ran out of space. You can check by running the following query to see if `tempdb` is currently using similar IDs:

```
SELECT * FROM tempdb.sys.allocation_units;
```